# Programmatically resizing NSSplitView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, appkit, nssplitview

I used to use and love RBSplitView, however I failed at reimplementing it programmatically as a certain version of xcode does not support IB plugins anymore.

Therefore I went back to using NSSplitView. NSSplitView is fine for what I need, the thing is that the autoSave of NSSplitView is broken. So I decided to implement it myself.

The thing I am doing at the moment is resizing 1 of the subviews of the NSSplitView.

What is the *proper* way of resizing an NSSplitView? - setPositionOfDivider:itIndex: should be the way to go ( haven't tried it ), however I do not know how to get the current position of the divider.

-- thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, `NSSplitView` hates you and wishes you harm. `RBSplitView` is so much better, it is worth IMO the headache of programatic layout (and I've been so burned with the ShortcutRecorder IB plugins that I will never go back to IB plugins).

That said....

The only way that I know of to determine the current position of the divider is to look at the subviews, find the divider's view, take it's frame, and work out its position keeping in mind the `dividerThickness`. It is insane that you have to write that code, but the code isn't that incredibly difficult, and you can put it in a category.

Or go back to `RBSplitView` while you still can, if your needs are ever going to be complicated.

Comment: Its for a simple chat window, my needs are not going to become anymore complicated any time soon. I am sure the code is not difficult was just wondering whether there is a *proper* way, as resizing 1 subview did work when the size was 0, anyways iam going to try this now and if it works you'll get a cookie

Comment: position = subView0.frame.size.height + subView0.frame.origin.x; works -- not the actual code but the way I did it and what does the job

Comment: Did you mean subView0.frame.size.width?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Swift here but the same method should exist in Objective C:

```
mySplitter.setPosition(123, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
```